# Float number regex with unexpected results

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex to validate float numbers:

```
var reg = /\d+\.?\d+/;
```

But it's validating this as true:

```
"11.34x"
"11.34abs"
"1a1.34abs"
```

The `\d` should only match numbers. What is happening?

Comment: So do you check for float numbers only? `\.?` means that it might be an integer value as well (though with minimum of 2 digits).

Comment: Do you want to allow scientific notation, like `-1e-10`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't **anchor** the regular expression, it will match a string that contains a substring that matches.

Try:

```
var reg = /^\d+\.?\d+$/;
```

The `^` matches the start of the test string, and `$` matches the end. Thus that regular expression will only match strings that have nothing but digits and at most one ".".

*edit* — as pointed out, your use of the `+` quantifier means your regex **requires** digits; if there's a decimal point, then it requires digits on both sides. Maybe that's what you want, maybe it isn't.

Comment: your regex is not match single digit `0-9`

Comment: @burning_LEGION ha well I just copied his :-)  You're right however. Thanks, I'll update

Comment: ... yeah, and maybe it is not the best way to validate float numbers.

Comment: @VisioN agreed - I'll add that too *edit* oh wait somebody else points that out.

Comment: Not the best approach though... I'd use `parseFloat(n) === +n` but only if the OP wants to check all number types, not only floats (considering his `?` in regex).

Comment: @VisioN the problem with `parseFloat()` is that it doesn't care if there are garbage characters at the end of the string, while the `Number()` function does. *edit* oh I see that's why you also do the `+n` part

Answer (score 2):

use this regular expression `^\d+(\.\d+)?$`

or `^\d+([.,]\d+)?$` separator can be comma or dot

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [`Number` wrapper/constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) instead:

```javascript
Number('11.34'); // => 11.34
Number('11.34x'); // => NaN
```

**[Edit]** As commenter @VisioN points out, that function has an edge case for empty and pure-whitespace strings, so maybe create a wrapper function:

```javascript
function reallyParseFloatingPointNumber(s) {
  var s = (''+s).trim();
  return (s==='') ? NaN : Number(s);
}
```

Comment: Bad idea. `Number("") === Number(" ") === 0`. And it won't work for floats only.

Comment: Arrggg... damn you, JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!"12 34.98 ".replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"").match(/^\d+\.?\d+$/))
  alert("Please enter numbers in float form")
else alert ("Good Form, Old Chap!")
```

Alas, I am mistaken again! burning_LEGION is correct:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?$/
```

will match single digits too.